# How to correctly set a constructor definition with object as a parameter

Tags: typescript, oop, constructor

I am writing a Request helper where I would like to define custom properties within an object rather than set them as parameters.

Therefore I would like the code below to work

```
import { IRequest } from './request'

export default class Request implements IRequest {
   constructor({baseUrl: string, timeout: string}: object) {}
}
```

Interface:

```
export interface IRequest {
   new: ({ baseUrl: string, timeout: number }: object): void
}
```

Without type `object` I can see an error that indicates that a parameter in constructor should have a `typedef`, which is fair - but when I assign `:object` (as above) I am getting: `[tslint] variable name clashes with keyword/type [variable-name]`.

Could you advice the proper way? I am probably doing something wrong with type definition. Tried `{[key: string]: any}` but no luck too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to pass an object that has the properties `baseUrl` and `timeout`, you need to name it first, then type it. Like this:

```
//         name: type
constructor(obj: {baseUrl: string, timeout: string}) {}
```

Simplified example:

```
class Example {
    constructor(obj: { baseUrl: string, timeout: string }) {
        console.log(obj.baseUrl);
        console.log(obj.timeout);
   }
}

const request = new Example({ baseUrl: 'localhost', timeout: '5s' });
```